# Get the value for the previous point of time. Clickhouse. IOT case

Tags: clickhouse

I have the table with keys *(time, facility)*. For each key, the (value) received from the sensor is stored. For instance:

```sql
┌─date───────┬facility┬value┬  
│ 2017-09-09 │ 10002  │ 10  │  
│ 2017-09-10 │ 10001  │ 12  │  
│ 2017-09-12 │ 10002  │ 15  │  
│ 2017-09-15 │ 10001  │ 17  │  
└────────────┴────────┘─────┘
```

I want to calculate an increase in the current value compared to the previous one. Something like this:

```sql
┌─date───────┬facility┬─value─┬  
│ 2017-09-12 │ 10002  │ 15/10 │ // 15 current, 10 previous for facility 10002  
│ 2017-09-15 │ 10001  │ 17/12 │ // 17 current, 12 previous for facility 10002  
└────────────┴────────┘───────┘
```

To get this result, I need to use JOIN, but as I understood from the documentation, the comparison condition in JOIN operation is only for equality, and inequalities cannot be used.

Of course, I can do a Cartesian product, then do a date comparison (get all dates less than the current one) in the WHERE section and then select the maximum date from the filtered ones. But it is very time and memory consuming!

Please help me create an optimal query, because this case is typical for IOT.

////////////////////////////////////////////
question extension
////////////////////////////////////////////

I also want to calculate the increment value compared to the value at the previous time for each row (for example, for each of 1 thousand rows). This situation is typical if I want to track sensor jumps. Example:

```sql
┌─date───────┬facility┬value┬  
│ 2017-09-01 │ 10002  │ 3   │  
│ 2017-09-02 │ 10001  │ 4   │  
│ 2017-09-04 │ 10002  │ 1   │  
│ 2017-09-05 │ 10001  │ 2   │  
│ 2017-09-09 │ 10002  │ 10  │  
│ 2017-09-10 │ 10001  │ 12  │  
│ 2017-09-12 │ 10002  │ 15  │  
│ 2017-09-15 │ 10001  │ 17  │  
└────────────┴────────┘─────┘
```

```sql
┌─date───────┬facility┬─value─┬  
│ 2017-09-04 │ 10002  │ 1/3   │ // 1 current,  3 previous for facility 10002  
│ 2017-09-05 │ 10001  │ 2/4   │ // 2 current,  4 previous for facility 10001  
│ 2017-09-09 │ 10002  │ 10/1  │ // 10 current, 1 previous for facility 10002  
│ 2017-09-10 │ 10001  │ 12/2  │ // 12 current, 2 previous for facility 10001  
│ 2017-09-12 │ 10002  │ 15/10 │ // 15 current, 10 previous for facility 10002  
│ 2017-09-15 │ 10001  │ 17/12 │ // 17 current, 12 previous for facility 10001  
└────────────┴────────┘───────┘
```

My table has the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SensorsLogs(
facility_id UInt64,
parameter_id UInt64,
timeSec DateTime('Asia/Yekaterinburg'),
value Float32 ) 
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(timeSec)
ORDER BY (facility_id, parameter_id, timeSec);
```

Comment: [GitHub: Get the value for the previous point of time. IOT case](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/11056)

Answer (score 2):

```
 select groupArray(1)(date)[1], facility, groupArray(2)(value) from 
  (select date,  facility, value from 
         (select '2017-09-09' date, 10002 facility, 10 value union all
          select '2017-09-10' , 10001, 12 union all
          select '2017-09-12' , 10002, 15 union all
          select '2017-09-15' , 10001, 17 ) 
   order by facility, date desc)
group by facility

┌─arrayElement(groupArray(1)(date), 1)─┬─facility─┬─groupArray(2)(value)─┐
│ 2017-09-15                           │    10001 │ [17,12]              │
│ 2017-09-12                           │    10002 │ [15,10]              │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. For "last lastpoint" case this approach will be work, but if I have to calculate such a value for each row? that is, for each row (for example, for 1 thousand rows), calculate the growth value compared to the value at the previous time?

Comment: @RomanShan as discussed at Github, you don't need CH. Try cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
  toDate(max(time)) AS date, 
  facility, 
  argMax(value, time) AS current_value, 
  argMin(value, time) AS previous_value,
  toString(current_value) || '/' || toString(previous_value) AS values
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    /* emulate the original table */
    SELECT toDateTime(test_set.1) as time, test_set.2 facility, test_set.3 value
    FROM ( 
      SELECT arrayJoin([
        ('2017-09-09 10:11:12', 10002, 10),
        ('2017-09-10 11:11:12', 10001, 12),
        ('2017-09-12 12:11:12', 10002, 15),
        ('2017-09-15 13:11:12', 10001, 17),
        ('2017-09-02 14:11:12', 10002,  5),
        ('2017-09-02 15:11:12', 10001,  7),
        ('2017-09-01 16:11:12', 10002,  7),
        ('2017-09-01 17:11:12', 10001,  9)]) test_set))
  /*WHERE time BETWEEN .. AND ..*/
  ORDER BY facility, time DESC
  LIMIT 2 BY facility)
GROUP BY facility
ORDER BY date;
/* result
┌───────date─┬─facility─┬─current_value─┬─previous_value─┬─values─┐
│ 2017-09-12 │    10002 │            15 │             10 │ 15/10  │
│ 2017-09-15 │    10001 │            17 │             12 │ 17/12  │
└────────────┴──────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴────────┘
*/
```

---

Query to find the previous value for each row (will use [neighbor](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/other-functions/#neighbor)-window function):

```sql
SELECT time, facility, value, 
    neighbor(facility, -1, -1) previous_facility,    
    (facility != previous_facility ? -1 : neighbor(value, -1, -1)) previous_value, 
    toString(value) || '/' || (previous_value = -1 ? 'none' : toString(previous_value)) AS values
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    /* emulate the original table */
    SELECT toDateTime(test_set.1) as time, test_set.2 facility, test_set.3 value
    FROM ( 
      SELECT arrayJoin([
        ('2017-09-01 01:02:03', 10002, 3 ),  
        ('2017-09-02 01:02:03', 10001, 4 ),  
        ('2017-09-04 01:02:03', 10002, 1 ),  
        ('2017-09-05 01:02:03', 10001, 2 ),  
        ('2017-09-09 01:02:03', 10002, 10),  
        ('2017-09-10 01:02:03', 10001, 12),  
        ('2017-09-12 01:02:03', 10002, 15),  
        ('2017-09-15 01:02:03', 10001, 17)]) test_set))
  /*WHERE time BETWEEN .. AND ..*/
  ORDER BY facility, time)
ORDER BY time;
/* result:
┌────────────────time─┬─facility─┬─value─┬─previous_facility─┬─previous_value─┬─values─┐
│ 2017-09-01 01:02:03 │    10002 │     3 │             10001 │             -1 │ 3/none │
│ 2017-09-02 01:02:03 │    10001 │     4 │                -1 │             -1 │ 4/none │
│ 2017-09-04 01:02:03 │    10002 │     1 │             10002 │              3 │ 1/3    │
│ 2017-09-05 01:02:03 │    10001 │     2 │             10001 │              4 │ 2/4    │
│ 2017-09-09 01:02:03 │    10002 │    10 │             10002 │              1 │ 10/1   │
│ 2017-09-10 01:02:03 │    10001 │    12 │             10001 │              2 │ 12/2   │
│ 2017-09-12 01:02:03 │    10002 │    15 │             10002 │             10 │ 15/10  │
│ 2017-09-15 01:02:03 │    10001 │    17 │             10001 │             12 │ 17/12  │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────┴───────────────────┴────────────────┴────────┘

*/
```

The similar query but using [runningDifference](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/other-functions/#other_functions-runningdifference):

```sql
SELECT time, facility, value, 
    neighbor(facility, -1, -1) previous_facility,    
    runningDifference(value) delta,
    (facility != previous_facility ? -1 : value - delta) AS previous_value,
    toString(value) || '/' || (previous_value = -1 ? 'none' : toString(previous_value)) AS values
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    /* emulate the original table */
    SELECT toDateTime(test_set.1) as time, test_set.2 facility, test_set.3 value
    FROM ( 
      SELECT arrayJoin([
        ('2017-09-01 01:02:03', 10002, 3 ),  
        ('2017-09-02 01:02:03', 10001, 4 ),  
        ('2017-09-04 01:02:03', 10002, 1 ),  
        ('2017-09-05 01:02:03', 10001, 2 ),  
        ('2017-09-09 01:02:03', 10002, 10),  
        ('2017-09-10 01:02:03', 10001, 12),  
        ('2017-09-12 01:02:03', 10002, 15),  
        ('2017-09-15 01:02:03', 10001, 17)]) test_set))
  /*WHERE time BETWEEN .. AND ..*/
  ORDER BY facility, time)
ORDER BY time;
/*
┌────────────────time─┬─facility─┬─value─┬─previous_facility─┬─delta─┬─previous_value─┬─values─┐
│ 2017-09-01 01:02:03 │    10002 │     3 │             10001 │   -14 │             -1 │ 3/none │
│ 2017-09-02 01:02:03 │    10001 │     4 │                -1 │     0 │             -1 │ 4/none │
│ 2017-09-04 01:02:03 │    10002 │     1 │             10002 │    -2 │              3 │ 1/3    │
│ 2017-09-05 01:02:03 │    10001 │     2 │             10001 │    -2 │              4 │ 2/4    │
│ 2017-09-09 01:02:03 │    10002 │    10 │             10002 │     9 │              1 │ 10/1   │
│ 2017-09-10 01:02:03 │    10001 │    12 │             10001 │    10 │              2 │ 12/2   │
│ 2017-09-12 01:02:03 │    10002 │    15 │             10002 │     5 │             10 │ 15/10  │
│ 2017-09-15 01:02:03 │    10001 │    17 │             10001 │     5 │             12 │ 17/12  │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────┴───────────────────┴───────┴────────────────┴────────┘
*/
```

---

The key *(time, facility)* is not pretty fit for calculations as above.

If it is **the main use-case** AND it works pretty **slow** in required date-ranges then consider changing the key to *(facility, time)* or using [Data Skipping Indexes](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#table_engine-mergetree-data_skipping-indexes).

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. For "last lastpoint" case this approach will be work, but if I have to calculate such a value for each row? that is, for each row (for example, for 1 thousand rows), calculate the growth value compared to the value at the previous time?

Comment: @RomanShan could you extend your question with this use-case & test example?

Comment: many thanks for the answer! Fields (time, facility) are already indexed in the table with the MergeTree engine (see new question update).

Will using the runningDifference function speed up the query? Will this function give the same result?

Comment: @RomanShan no problem. I added the query that uses runningDifference. I think neighbor or runningDifference takes the same execution time (you can test it on your dataset). To speed the query up needs to find/define the most optimal primary key - try to make several experiments to find the most efficient one for your use-cases.